# Classification LDA vs. TFIDF

Tags: machine-learning, gensim, lda, text-classification

I was running Multi-label classification on text data I noticed TFIDF outperformed LDA by a large margin. TFIDF accuracy was aorund 50% and LDA was around 29%.

Is this expected or should LDA do better than this?

Answer (score 2):

LDA is normally used for unsupervised learning, not for classification. It provides a generative model, not a discriminative model ([What is the difference between a Generative and Discriminative Algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879432/what-is-the-difference-between-a-generative-and-discriminative-algorithm)), which makes it less optimal for classification. LDA can also be sensitive to data preprocessing and model parameters.